# USB driver error for VMWare

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, usb, vmware

Good afternoon everyone! I hope here will help with the problem (see the attachment). This message appears when I try to switch the device (iphone) to a virtual machine (macOS sierra).

```
vm => removable dev. => iphone
```

**The message appears: "The connection for the USB device 'Apple Iphone' was unsuccessful. Driver error."**

That did what to solve:

1. Removed the parameter `UpperFilters` at `HKLM \ system \ currentcontrolset \ control \ class \ {36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}`
2. `VM` updated to `12.5.6 build-5528349`
3. Checked the USB `ATI` filter through the installation wizard - it's not there
4. set the usb params in the VM to `USB 2.0`

I will be glad to any help! Thank you!
p.s.: win 7, 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the connection of the wire to the `usb 3.0` connector, since `usb 3.0` was installed in the `VMWare` settings. The problem was eliminated when you connect the iphone to `usb 2.0`.